# Tkinter (Python) não permite alteração do tamanho da letra da caixa de texto com manutenção das suas dimensões

Tags: python, tkinter, text

Quero que o usuário possa aumentar ou reduzir a fonte do texto que é digitado no widget "Text" do Tkinter com a ajuda de botões com eventos programados. Ocorre que as dimensões do widget acompanham o tamanho da fonte, de forma que a própria caixa de texto aumenta ou diminui junto à fonte. Aparentemente esse widget tem dificuldade para manter um tamanho absoluto. Solicito auxílio. Fiz um exemplo funcional do que acontece:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font

def aumentar_fonte():
    fonte_atual = font.Font(font=texto['font'])
    tamanho_atual = fonte_atual.actual()['size']
    nova_fonte = font.Font(size=tamanho_atual + 2)
    texto.configure(font=nova_fonte)

def reduzir_fonte():
    fonte_atual = font.Font(font=texto['font'])
    tamanho_atual = fonte_atual.actual()['size']
    nova_fonte = font.Font(size=tamanho_atual - 2)
    texto.configure(font=nova_fonte)

root = tk.Tk()

texto = tk.Text(root, width=37, height=10)
texto.pack()

frame_botoes = tk.Frame(root)
frame_botoes.pack()

btn_aumentar = tk.Button(frame_botoes, text="Aumentar Fonte", command=aumentar_fonte)
btn_aumentar.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

btn_reduzir = tk.Button(frame_botoes, text="Reduzir Fonte", command=reduzir_fonte)
btn_reduzir.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se queres que o widget fique sempre do mesmo tamanho podes criar uma frame, inserir a widget dentro do frame e depois inserir o frame na root.

```
text_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=200)
text_frame.pack_propagate(0)
texto = tk.Text(text_frame, width=1, height=1)
texto.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

text_frame.pack()
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!
Adicionei o código abaixo antes de text_frame.pack() e obtive a barra de rolagem, imitando perfeitamente o comportamento de uma <textarea> com o efeito similar em Javascript:

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(texto)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
texto.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=texto.yview)